# Why is Azure function Invocation Id empty?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kql, appinsights

I am trying to fetch invocation id of an Azure Function using the app insights query:

```
requests
| project
    id,
    operation_Name,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'appname' and operation_Name =~ 'Gen'
```

And The result table shows no value for invocation id:

[image]

Am I missing something? Please let me know in the comment If I can add more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue as I have got the ***invocation Id*** in the logs by following the below steps:

1. Created the Function App (.Net Core 6 Stack) in Azure with the HTTP Trigger Function Class inside the Azure Portal.
2. Open the Function App> Click on Logs in Monitoring Menu (left index pane) > Close this dialog box

[image]

3. Copied your query to get the results, where in the query:
   `cloud_RoleName` is given as `FunctionAppName`,
   `operation_Name` is given as `FunctionName`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying, @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT. Even the same steps worked for me in a new function app. But I am not sure why the invocation id in my existing function app is not displayed. Invocation Id is a system-defined value but why's that missing in my case? FYI, I have deployed this app using ARM template. Am I missing to configure something that displays the invocation id?

Comment: Could you please provide your ARM template, parameters used to deploy it?